# Will time distortions disappear if I rest at camp?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I got notified that a time distortion was forming while I was on an expedition. However, several of my Pokémon are injured and need healing.

Will the time distortion disappear if I rest at a camp to heal my Pokémon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time distortions won't disappear after a short rest, but they may disappear after a long rest.

I quick traveled to a camp to test for myself. The time distortion (visible in the background of the video below) didn't disappear after resting at camp for "Just a little while". However, the distortion did disappear after I rested "Until nightfall".

Comment: It's worth noting that a space-time distortion can disappear also saving and restarting the game